# Asp.Net 5 with Angular2: Webpack + HMR?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, asp.net-core, webpack-hmr

I initially tested Asp.net Core + Angular2 and I was quite happy with it, but I got to the point I've to use external library(in my case, `iTextSharp`) in a project referenced by the web app. I didn't found a workaround to use library of the .Net Framework in a .Net core Class library project, so I guess I've to move back to Asp.Net MVC 5.

Now:

Is it possible to have an Asp.Net MVC5 + WebPackMiddleware + hot module replacement? Is there a template available for this configuration?

Comment: This question is not suitable for StackOverflow: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._ Please check the help center on how to ask on-topic http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, amongst other **a specific programming problem** and **a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development**

Comment: @Tseng My question is more about is it possible to have those 3 technologies running together and the template is only a way to show it.

Comment: There is no reason why it wouldn't be possible. However, I also don't see a reason why you'd have to go back to MVC5 anyways. ASP.NET Core is not .NET Core exclusive. It runs on both, .NET Core and .NET Framework. Any reason why you can't/don't want to use ASP.NET Core against .NET Framework >=4.5?